# How to make Sharp Corner Switch in iOS

Tags: ios, uiswitch

I am a beginner ios developer.

The UISwitch is round corner by default in iOS 6, seems no way to change it in storyboard. 

And I don't know how to coding a sharp corner switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following switch:

https://github.com/twotoasters/TTSwitch

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to have sharp corners on the standard UISwitch. You would need to subclass and create your own UISwitch with custom art assets or drawing.

Check out this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23424/photoshop-for-developers-creating-a-custom-uiswitch) to customize switches. They don't use sharp corners, but it shows how to customize the look of a UISwitch